# how to get wine programs to appear in program searches like they do in Mint?

Tags: unity, wine, launcher, mint

When I install an .exe program via Wine when on Linux Mint, it automatically shows up as a program in my program list when I search for it from the launcher:

[image]

How can I get this behavior to work automagically when installing a windows program in Ubuntu 16.04?  My Ubuntu install is the netboot image with the ubuntu-desktop package.  Currently I have to open wine programs from the command line or by navigating to the exe in C:\program files\

Comment: Is it only wine programs that aren't appearing in Dash or all programs?

Comment: Only wine. Everything else is there.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't any kind of official process but it works fantastic for me.  First I install Windows programs using PlayOnLinux. I then let it create a launcher for me which ends up on the Desktop.  Finally I move the .desktop launcher file to

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

I've used this method for a year or so on about a dozen programs and it works great

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like, when you install a program using Wine it takes care of it automatically. If for some reason Wine doesn't add your program to the dash (Ubuntu's startup menu), you can add it manually following this description:
 [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles | Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)